# Get MAC Address without connect to WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, mac-address

Is it possible to get WiFi MAC Address without actually connected to it?

Let's say I have android device "A".
I already turn on the WiFi, so that my android device is now able to detect nearby WiFi SSID broadcasted.

Nearby I have a few WiFi SSIDs broadcasted as listed below:

> SSID=hype, MAC_ADDRESS=00:39:E0:33:00
>   SSID=dummy, MAC_ADDRESS=02:33:DF:39:89
>   SSID=bilbo, MAC_ADDRESS=D0:32:E8:97:29

Without actually connected to WiFi SSID `bilbo`, can I have its MAC_ADDRESS?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
        {
           List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
           for (ScanResult ap : results) {
               Log.d(TAG, "SSID=" + ap.SSID + " MAC=" + ap.BSSID); 
           }
        }
}, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)); 
wifiManager.startScan();
```

[For a BSS operating in infrastructure mode, the BSSID is the MAC address of the wireless access point (WAP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_%28802.11_network%29)

Comment: amazing! thanks @msh! but you need to add these lines first to Android Manifest file:  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />`

Answer (score 3):

Try this bash shell to get the MAC address

`cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address`

It returns the MAC address under `adb shell`.