# Find if connected to specific WiFi

Tags: android

I've been trying to create an app that will recognize when my phone is connected to a desired network and when it is, then it will add a number to a variable and perform tasks such as start a new app. I have looked around and haven't found a good answer.
Also, I've checked the android docs and I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. 
I know that by using the isConnected method I can find out if I'm connected to a WiFi network but it doesn't tell me if it is the one I want. 
In this direction, I have read that one can possibly achieve this by finding the mac address or the bssid of the network.
,
P.s coding on android using AIDE

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is call broadcast receiver. basically, you create a custom broadcast receiver that will receive message on some actions. you define those action in an intent filter :

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

then register your receiver on this intent filter :

```
registerReceiver(wifiWatcher, intentFilter);
```

and your receiver will implement the onReceive method :

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )

ConnectivityManager conMngr = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = conMngr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
  String ssid = null;
  NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
  if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (connectionInfo != null && !StringUtil.isBlank(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
      ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
    }
  }
```

Well, do what you want if the correct SSID

```
if (ssid!=null && ssid.equals(mySSID){
//DO
}
```

to do that, you need to add those permissions in your manifest :

```
  <user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: I will try both and see which one works best, thanks.

Comment: You can mark your favorite FAQ by clicking the "up arrow" or mark the correct answer by clicking the "tick".

Comment: I tried to but it told me I needed at least 15 rep points to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You should start first by finding your mac address from your router, etc.

Next, you filter that on your android device:
1. [Can I find the MAC address of my Access point in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063889/can-i-find-the-mac-address-of-my-access-point-in-android).
2. [Get MAC Address without connect to WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549373/get-mac-address-without-connect-to-wifi). 
Once you managed to do that that, next you can perform the operations you want.